# CodeIgniter - base_url() function not working

Tags: php, codeigniter

I'm trying to combine CodeIgniter with free Bootstrap template.
The problem is, when I try to load DataTable library it's not loading at all.
I already try a few code but all code that load from local source doesn't work, when I tried to load from online source it work.

```
// Not Working
<script src="<?php echo base_url() ?>assets/bootstrap/plugins/datatables/jquery.dataTables.min.js"></script>
<script src="<?php echo base_url() ?>assets/bootstrap/plugins/datatables/dataTables.bootstrap.min.js"></script>'

// Not Working
<script src="<?php echo base_url('assets/bootstrap/plugins/datatables/jquery.dataTables.min.js') ?>"></script>
<script src="<?php echo base_url('assets/bootstrap/plugins/datatables/dataTables.bootstrap.min.js') ?>"></script>

// Not Working
<script src="<?php echo base_url()."assets" ?>/bootstrap/plugins/datatables/jquery.dataTables.min.js"></script>
<script src="<?php echo base_url()."assets" ?>/bootstrap/plugins/datatables/dataTables.bootstrap.min.js"></script>

// Working
<script src="http://ajax.aspnetcdn.com/ajax/jQuery/jquery-2.2.3.min.js"></script>
<script src="http://ajax.aspnetcdn.com/ajax/jquery.dataTables/1.9.0/jquery.dataTables.min.js"></script>
```

I'm sure that the link for local source already typed correctly.
Is there any Route or Security problem?

Comment: any console errors ?

Comment: Did you configure `base_url`?

Comment: no error found.

Comment: Yes, already configure `base_url` in `config.php`

Comment: i mean console errors not php errors

Comment: @madalinivascu Thanks, I just check using Google Developer Tools and found an error, it said `Uncaught TypeError: Cannot read property 'getContext' of undefined`

Comment: Certainly this is a path issue ... You need to look into browser console watch for the http requests and make sure there are no 404 erros.  In Firefox you can bring up the Browser console by ctr+shift+k  enable the "net"  monitoring and reload the page.

Answer (score 1):

You have to load URL helper. To  load in `config/autoload.php` file and add following code

```
$autoload['helper'] = array('url');
```

**OR**

in controller add following code

```
$this->load->helper('url');
```

then go to `config.php` in config folder and set

```
$config['base_url'] = 'http://example.com/';
```

Answer (score 0):

Place this script

`<script src="http://ajax.aspnetcdn.com/ajax/jQuery/jquery-2.2.3.min.js"></script>`

At the top(Above all other script)

Answer (score 0):

It Fixed,

The problem is the sort order on calling the JS, have to sort it like this:

```
<!-- jQuery 2.2.3 -->
<script src="<?php echo base_url() ?>assets/bootstrap/plugins/jQuery/jquery-2.2.3.min.js"></script>
<!-- Bootstrap 3.3.6 -->
<script src="<?php echo base_url() ?>assets/bootstrap/bootstrap/js/bootstrap.min.js"></script>
<!-- DataTables -->
<script src="<?php echo base_url() ?>assets/bootstrap/plugins/datatables/jquery.dataTables.min.js"></script>
<script src="<?php echo base_url() ?>assets/bootstrap/plugins/datatables/dataTables.bootstrap.min.js"></script>
```

and then another external sources.
Thanks everyone.

Answer (score 0):

You Can Also Use another function like site_url()